# HTML+Ajax+servlet not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

hi im trying out a servlet based ajax  here in my program im using a html page with button and textbox when i click the button it should fire some ajax request to the server done some computations and return result in the same page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>


    </head>
    <body>
       <h3>Ajax in servlets</h3>

        <div id="change"> hi there</div>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="solo">
        <input type="button" align="center" value="Ajax" onclick="ajaxreq()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

in this html page a text box and a button when i click on the button it should execute the following java script function

```
 var xmlreq=null;
            var a=document.getElementById("fname");
            function ajaxreq(){


                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xmlreq=new XMLHttpRequest();

                }
                    else if(window.ActiveXObject){
                        xmlreq=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    try{
                  xmlreq.onreadystatechange=response;
                     xmlreq.open("GET","Servlethello?an=+a",true);
                        xmlreq.send();

        }
                    catch(e){

                        alert("some error")
                    }
    }
function response(){
var res=xmlreq.responseText;
document.write(res);
alert(res);
document.getElementById("change").innerHTML=res;

                  }








        </script>
  here i have created a ajax call and send the request to the servlet Servlethello



public class Servlethello extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,
                     HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException {
res.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
out.println("<h1>");
String a=req.getParameter(an);
out.println("solorules"+a);
out.println("</h1>");
out.close();


}


    }
```

the variable a fetches the value entered in the textbox and send it to the servlet
 xmlreq.open("GET","Servlethello?an=+a",true); to this servlet

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,
                     HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException {
res.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
out.println("<h1>");
String a=req.getParameter(an);
out.println("solorules"+a);
out.println("</h1>");
```

and this servlet should be displayed here
    hi there using this java script

```
var res=xmlreq.responseText;
    document.write(res);
    alert(res);
    document.getElementById("change").innerHTML=res;
```

Comment: someone just put a vote to close this question instead of adding a comment.  What thye should of done is ask you - can you explain "not working"  what exactly is happening , what is supposed to happen?  are you seeing any errors?  things of that nature should be added in your question , not just pasting your code here and writing "This Doesn't Work , fix for me"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery ajax , it very simple rather than pure JS ajax.

See the below  link 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Sample Code :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  dataType:"html"
  context: document.body
}).done(function(res) {
 alert(res);
});
```

With Pure JS :

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
   }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

For more detail referbelow link :
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: is it possible to do it without jquery

Comment: you were getting the request from text file ,what if i want to get response from servlet,im getting status=0,readystate=1

Answer (score 0):

Hi use following sample jquery script to make ajax call

```
 function makeAjaxCall(){
    $.ajax({
        var data = ""; // if you want to pass data as request param then assign here
        url: // your servelt path here......,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data, status, er) {
            alert(er);
        }
    });
 }
```